# Wine won't run any .exe programs that are installed on other Drives

Tags: wine, games, executable

whit 10.10 I did't had this problem I was able to run programs from my windows Drive through Wine by just double-clicking or selecting run by Wine, but in 11.04 when I run program this way it says :

> The file '/media/Drive/Software/Games/Borderlands/Gearbox Software/Borderlands/Binaries/Borderlands.exe' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit.

and I try changing permissions of file to be executable but it keeps changing back every time i change it

[image]

I read that it's blocked because of windows viruses but i'm sure that this files are safe and I can run them safely but now how can I change it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not manage to chmod  the .exe to be executable, you can always fall back to using the command line to run the .exe. ie:

*wine /media/Drive/Softwaretorun.exe*   or if theres spaces in the path.

*wine "/media/Drive/Soft Ware.exe"*

The whole '.exe' must be executable - is a nice way to put another layer of security on things, but when the .exe is on a filesystem that you can not make the .exe executable (such as on an ISO, or remote share, or ntfs/vfat mounted with options where its not the default) it can cause problems.

The Command line way of running a .exe should always work.

Just for extra clarification, you can not change the modes or permissions of files on a NTFS/Vfat once they are mounted. You must mount them with the proper options, then the options normally set ALL files on the ntfs/vfat to be executable, this is often a bigger annoyance then the wine not working annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

install [ntfs-config](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ntfs-config)

then tick the "Enable write support for internal devices" chekbox

if your windows drive not mounted automatically, type in terminal

```
sudo mountall
```

or reboot

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this from the command line.

```
chmod +x /media/Drive/Software/Games/Borderlands/Gearbox Software/Borderlands/Binaries/Borderlands.exe
```

...and if Linux refuses to <s>[make you a sandwich](http://xkcd.com/149/)</s> add the permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /media/Drive/Software/Games/Borderlands/Gearbox Software/Borderlands/Binaries/Borderlands.exe
```